# How to use forloop to create a sequence of columns

Tags: r

I need to create the variable x out of the variable y as below.

```
df$x<-0
df$x<-ifelse(df$y==0 | df$y==1, 1, 0)
df$x[is.na(df$x)] <- 0
```

However i hhave y ranging from 1 to 52, which means i need to create x1 thru x52. I am an avid stata user and it is pretty straight forward to do using the forval function. However I am having difficulties doing it in R. I thought about the following, but it didn't workout very well:

```
for (i in 1:52){
  df$x[i] <- 0
.
.
.
}
```

I thought i could let r replace the i by the values from the loop the same way stata does.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Here an example using dummy data:

```
set.seed(123)
#Data
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(520),nrow = 10,ncol = 52))
names(df) <- paste0('y',1:52)
#new names
vals <- paste0('x',1:52)
#Loop
for(i in vals)
{
  df[[i]]<-0
  df[[i]]<-ifelse(df[[gsub('x','y',i)]]==0 | df[[gsub('x','y',i)]]==1, 1, 0)
  df[[i]][is.na(df[[i]])] <- 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you had data that looked something like this:

```
data
   x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10
1   1  3  0 NA  3 NA  3  1  2   3
2   1  1 NA NA  3  0  3  3  0   0
3   0  1  1  0  2  2  1  1  0   1
4   0 NA  2  1  3  2 NA  0  2   0
5   1  2 NA  2  0  1  2  3  2   3
6   3 NA  1  3 NA NA NA  3 NA   3
7   2 NA  3  3 NA  0 NA  1  1   1
8  NA  3  2  1  1 NA  1  0  1   2
9   0  1  0 NA NA  0  2  0 NA   2
10  1  0  3  0  3  2 NA  0  1   2
```

One approach might be to use `dplyr::mutate` with `across`:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  mutate(across(everything(),~ ifelse(. %in% c(0,1), 1, 0),
                .names = "y{.col}")) %>%
  rename_all(~str_replace(.,"yx","y"))
   x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10 y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6 y7 y8 y9 y10
1   2  1  2  2  2  2  0  1  1   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  1   1
2   3  2  3  1  3  3  3  2  0   1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1   1
3   0  2  2  1  0  2  3  0  2   0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0   1
4   2  2  3  1  0  0  1  1  2   3  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0   0
5   1  3  1  2  2  2  3  2  3   3  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
6   3  1  1  1  0  3  2  2  1   2  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1   0
7   1  1  3  1  3  1  1  0  1   2  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  1   0
8   1  2  3  3  2  1  2  2  2   0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   1
9   1  2  3  0  2  3  0  0  2   1  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0   1
10  2  0  1  0  3  2  3  2  2   3  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   0
```

Example data:

```
set.seed(123)
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA,0:3),100,replace = TRUE),ncol =10))
names(data) <- paste0("x",1:10)
```